# If column includes a certain value, turn top cell red

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want a function that can check one column for a certain value and if at least one value is found then the top cell should become red. This is an intent to visualize the function of the top cell in said column:

```
IF any cell in Column "A" = "X" THEN cellbgcolor = red ELSE cellbgcolor=white
```

I don't mind doing it in two steps, i.e. if value found type "X" in cell and use conditional formatting to paint the cell.

Comment: You can just use conditional formatting. No other steps needed.

Comment: Well, I do need another step, since I don´t want to color the cell of the value, I want to color the top cell if any cell in a column has a certain value.

Comment: You can do that with conditional formatting. CF can refer to other cells, and uses absolute references by default.

Comment: @pnuts, so it was you, Mr. A-hair-away-from-10k! Congrats.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I couldn´t find how to do it with conditional formatting. Maybe I´m just blind =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MATCH("X",A:A,0)
```

with <strike>Applies to</strike> Range: A1.